# Handling lists of two different types with same code using functional programming in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, functional-programming

I have two lists with different types list1 and list2 . I have a method which does the same operation on the lists.

I'm using lambdas where I cannot access the property as (it.prop1) if I'm using List of type Any.

Is there any solution to avoid this issue with lambdas?

```
val list1: List<Student> = ..
val list2: List<Teacher> = ..

list1.filter {
    school.contains(it.prop1) }
.forEach {
    total +=  it.prop2.toLong()
}

list2.filter {
    school.contains(it.prop1) }
.forEach {
    total +=  it.prop2.toLong()
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Do `Student` and `Teacher` have a common interface which exposes `prop1` and `prop2`?

Comment: No, they dont implement a common interface

Comment: Well then you can add an interface and process `list1` and `list2` with the same code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
object Test {

    private fun isContains(school: Set<Int>, any: Any) = when (any) {
        is Student -> school.contains(any.prop1)
        is Teacher -> school.contains(any.prop1)
        else -> false
    }

    private fun value(any: Any) = when (any) {
        is Student -> any.prop2
        is Teacher -> any.prop2
        else -> throw NoWhenBranchMatchedException("any should be Student or Teacher")
    }

    @JvmStatic
    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        val school = setOf(1, 2)
        val list = listOf(Student(1, 1), Student(2, 2), Student(3, 3), Teacher(1, 1), Teacher(2, 2), Teacher(3, 3))

        val total = list.filter {
            isContains(school, it)
        }.map {
            value(it)
        }.sum()

        println("Total: $total")
    }

    private class Student(val prop1: Int, val prop2: Int)

    private class Teacher(val prop1: Int, val prop2: Int)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't. You can take advantage of common interface.

For example:

```
interface Human{
    val age: Int
}

class Student(override val age: Int): Human

class Teacher(override val age: Int, val salary: Double):Human

fun x(){
    val list1: List<Student> = ...
    val list2: List<Teacher> = ...
    val school: List<Human> = ...

    val result = school
        .filter { it is Student }
        .sumBy { it.age}

    val result2 = school
        .filter { it is Teacher }
        .sumBy { it.age }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use [Type Checks and Casts](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html)

```
class Student(val prop1:Int, val prop2:Int)
class Teacher(val prop1:Int, val prop2:Int)
val list : List<Any> = listOf(Student(1,1),Student(2,2),Student(3,3),Teacher(1,1),Teacher(2,2),Teacher(3,3))
var total : Long = 0
val school : Array<Int> = arrayOf(1,2)
list.filter{
    if(it is Student)
    {
        school.contains((it as Student).prop1)
    }
    else if(it is Teacher)
    {
        school.contains((it as Teacher).prop1)
    }
    else
    {
        false
    }
}.forEach{
    if(it is Student)
    {
        total += (it as Student).prop2.toLong()
    }
    else if(it is Teacher)
    {
        total += (it as Teacher).prop2.toLong()
    }

}
println(total)  //print 6 in this example
```

This is ugly tough. It is better to make `Student` and `Teacher` either inherit a common superclass or implement a common interface